# DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE to subdirectory

Tags: linux, oracle

I have a pretty simple piece of code, that just writes object source to the server.

```
DECLARE
    data CLOB;
    objType varchar2(30) := 'PACKAGE_SPEC';
    objSchema varchar2(30) := 'TEST';
    objName varchar2(30) := 'TEST';
    fname varchar2(256) := objName || '.sql';
BEGIN
    SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(objType,objName,objSchema) into data from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(fname);
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(data,'SVN',fname);
END;
/
```

SVN is a directory

```
create or replace directory svn as '/tmp/svn'
```

I was wondering if I could write into subdirectory of svn, but that doesn't seem to work
e.g.

```
DECLARE
    data CLOB;
    objType varchar2(30) := 'PACKAGE_SPEC';
    objSchema varchar2(30) := 'TEST';
    objName varchar2(30) := 'TEST';
    fname varchar2(256) := objType || '/'|| objName || '.sql';
BEGIN
    SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(objType,objName,objSchema) into data from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(fname);
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(data,'SVN',fname);
END;
/
```

just ignores the part before "/".
Is there a way to write into a subdirectory or do I have to create a (oracle) directory for every path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lieu of any definitive information, it seems reasonable that `dbms_xlsprocessor` either uses `utl_file` or the same underlying mechanisms. The [documentation for `utl_file`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#ARPLS069) has an example that says "subdirectories are not accessible", but more usefully [`fopen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#ARPLS069) states:

> If a directory path is given as a part of the filename, it is ignored by `FOPEN`.

Which matches the behaviour you're seeing; you don't get an error, the file is just created in the directory pointed to by the `directory` object, and the subdirectory part you supplied is being ignored.

So yes, you will need to create an Oracle `directory` object for every path you want to write to, and provide that directory object's name to `clob2file`.